# Override queryset filters while generating django admin URLs

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-urls

My models.py looks like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Lecture(models.Model):
    Speaker = model.ForeignKey(Person)
    Topic = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Choices = ((1,"Upcoming"),(2,"In Progress",),(3,"Completed"))
    Status = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=Choices, default=1, max_length=1)
```

My admin.py looks like this:

```
class LectureAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Lecture.objects.exclude(Status='Completed')
```

So my change list view in the django admin for the Lecture model shows only Lectures in "Upcoming" and "In Progress" status. This works fine.

Now I need to get the URL for the list of all lectures to be passed as a view somewhere else.The standard way of doing this in the django admin is by reversing the URL, so I do this:

```
urlresolvers.reverse('admin:%s_%s_changelist' % (app_label, model_name))
```

However, when I do this,I get the the filtered Queryset with Lectures in "Completed" state missing.How do I construct a url reverse function to get entire Lecture queryset and not the filtered queryset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a workaround, looks ugly, I understand.

Add `all` GET parameter to the `changelist` url:

```
url = urlresolvers.reverse('admin:%s_%s_changelist' % (app_label, model_name))
url += '?all'
```

Call [`get_queryset()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) on `super()`, exclude `Completed` status only if there is no `all` in `request.GET`:

```
class LectureAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(LectureAdmin, self).get_queryset(request) 
        if 'all' not in request.GET:
            qs = qs.exclude(Status='Completed')
        return qs
```

UPD (applying other filters from `request.GET`):

```
from xadmin.plugin.related import RELATE_PREFIX  # or just set RELATE_PREFIX = '_rel_'

qs = qs.filter(**{key[len(RELATE_PREFIX):]: value 
                  for key, value in request.GET.iteritems() 
                  if key.startswith(RELATE_PREFIX)})
```

`**` unpacks the dictionary into keyword arguments.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: How is this different from queryset method that i employed

Comment: @Amistad I've updated the answer. Give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: This is one clever hack..works for me..and beauty lies in the eyes of the beholder..looks beautiful to me !!

Comment: @alecxe..I have one more problem..I am using the urlresolvers specifically to find the URL which will give me in my case the list of lectures associated with a speaker..the url that I have is college/lectures/?_rel_Speaker__id__exact=1 where college is the app name and id is the automatically generated primary key by Django..how do I incorporate your solution with this setup..I can edit my original question if it is not clear..

Comment: The exact function that does that is [here](https://github.com/sshwsfc/django-xadmin/blob/master/xadmin/plugins/relate.py#L57) ...Can you please let me know what changes I can make there..

Comment: @Amistad gotcha, I think you need to add smth like this `qs = qs.filter(**{key[len(RELATE_PREFIX):]: value for key, value in request.GET.iteritems() if key.startswith(RELATE_PREFIX)})`, where `RELATE_PREFIX` is equal to `_rel_` (see [source](https://github.com/sshwsfc/django-xadmin/blob/master/xadmin/plugins/relate.py#L14)). Is that it?

Comment: @alecxe..that looks very much like what I want..However my python skills are at best elementary..still trying to understand the solution..Is that a list comprehension..also,if it is not an issue,can you edit your actual answer so that I can understand it better..

Comment: sorry if I am bugging you..but will                                  `if '_rel_' not in request.GET:
   qs = qs.exclude(Status='Completed')` not work ?

Comment: @Amistad nope `_rel_` is just a part of one of possible parameters. To check the `_rel_` substring - you need to iterate over `request.GET` items and check every parameter key for starting with `_rel_`.

Comment: I played around a little..this worked.. `qs = super(ChangeAdmin, self).queryset()
        if any([key for key in self.request.GET.keys() if '_rel_' in key.lower()]):
            qs = qs.filter(Change_status='Completed')
        return qs`  ... thanks for the help..

Answer (score 0):

`get_queryset()` is the basic queryset used in admin listing, thus you wo'nt be able to get all the records if you override it this way.

Possible solutions:

- use filters ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_vertical ) to exclude unwanted records (these with `Status='Completed'`

or

- create proxy model for `Lecture`, register it in admin and use modified `get_queryset()` in given listing. Proxy model is required because each model can have registered only single `AdminModel` class

models.py

```
class IncompletedLecture(Lecture):

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

admin.py

```
class IncompletedAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset():
        return Lecture.query.exclude(Status='Completed')

admin.site.register(IncompletedLecture, IncompletedAdmin)
```

Comment: I use django reversion in the admin for object history and reversion..Reversion does not work with proxy models..